# A way to programmatically add people to my Google+ circles

Tags: google-plus

Back when Google+ was just launched, my friend and I started a service that works as a directory of Lithuanians using Google+. The Lithuanian Google+ community is small, yet rather vibrant and interesting. The website currently has around 1,400 people in 7 categories. I'd like to create 7 circles corresponding to those categories in my own Google+ account, and programmatically add all the listed people to one of them (adding them manually is *a bit* too much work).

Is there a way to do this? I tried playing with Chrome's JavaScript console to trigger mouse clicks on the *Add to circles* button, but that does not seem to work. Google+ API does not (at least currently) provide such a possibility either. And while unsure, I feel that any Chrome macros or Mac Automator scripts could not be used for clicking on a button within a website (in addition to that, the button is created with JavaScript).

Comment: Changes to the API are coming fast and furious. I expect that adding people to Circles is something they'll implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there's a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lgejhoiengobafehdiejgcdnogdngeej?hc=search&hcp=main) for this.

> This extension allows you to easily add Google+ profiles listed on ANY webpage to your Google+ circles.
>
> It first collects a listing of your circles and adds them to a dropdown box so you can choose which circle you would like the profiles to be added to.  It then scans the current page you are on for Google+ Profile IDs and tries to add them to the given circle.  Once it is able to do this it will give a listing of every person that has been added (by image and name.)

Comment: Please add information so that future users will be able to benefit from this answer.

Comment: Will keep that in mind, thank's for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)? It's a browser automation framework.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out later tonight and let you know how it went.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Seems like the issue is related to the fact that the button is created with JavaScript - just like my console example. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score -1):

See [Circle Management](https://plus.google.com/100283465826629314254/about) - This API was just released and seems to be powerful. It may help you

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications. Please don't post naked links, if they break your answer becomes useless. How does this "Circle Management" solve the problem? Please summarize the details and detail how it can help then add the link for reference. As you are new here, I would advise you to read the [FAQ] as this site is a Q&A site not a forum. Thanks